# How to use {env_name} conditionally in a xonsh prompt

Tags: python, xonsh

In the [`xonsh`](https://github.com/xonsh/xonsh/) shell how can I use the name of the virtual environment I'm use as a condition in the definition of `$PROMPT`?

(More in detail: I have a virtual environment called `'xonsh'` for the xonsh shell itself, but I do not want this venv to be shown in the prompt, but any other activated venv should be shown in the prompt.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by looking at `xonsh/prompt/env.py` to see how we define the `env_name` function -- since you use virtualenv, you can do something like the following in your `xonshrc`:

```
import os.path

def env_name_cust(pre_chars="(", post_chars=")"):
    """Extract the current environment name from $VIRTUAL_ENV 
    """
    env_path = __xonsh__.env.get("VIRTUAL_ENV", "")
    env_name = os.path.basename(env_path)
    if env_name and env_name != 'xonsh':
        return pre_chars + env_name + post_chars
```

Then add that function to the `$PROMPT_FIELDS` dictionary:

`$PROMPT_FIELDS['env_name_cust'] = env_name_cust`

Then you can use `{env_name_cust}` in your `$PROMPT` formatting string in place of the default `{env_name}`

You can also use `${...}` as a substitute for `__xonsh__.env` if you like.

Comment: Works a treat! Thanks. I had tried assigning a function straight to $PROMPT but didn't get to a working version with it.